# Database design for Domain Driven Design

Tags: c#

I am doing some reverse engineering on classic N layered app and making it DDD.
From the current implementation there is an Entity Person, with too much info, so i separated that in Domain. Here is what i have:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; protected set; }
    public string LastName { get; protected set; }
    public string Email { get; protected set; }

    public Address Address { get; protected set; }

    public IReadOnlyList<Phone> Phones { get; protected set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string City { get; protected set; }
    public string Postal { get; protected set; }
}

public class Phone
{
    ///
}
```

And additional methods per class, setThis, getThat etc.
I did this because i want to avoid the classical object value with EF, one column in SQL with all the information.
My question is, what is the best practice to design database table for Person?
I am aware of the possibility to have 3 separate tables in db with FK, or to go with 1 table and have an entity for that, for example PersonEntity: Person

Any advice is appreciated

Comment: Given the code shown, you would at least need a `Person` table and a `Phone` table (which has a foreign key back to `Person`).  It's not really clear what more information or help you need than that, though.

Comment: By additional info i mean Person can have SocialSecurityNumber, Phone can have landline, mobile, active number for daytime, separate for night time, there is a possibility to have more then 1 Address. This is why i was thinking 3 tables, Person, Phone, Address but i'm not sure do i need an Address table

Comment: `"there is a possibility to have more then 1 Address"` - Not in that model there isn't.  A `Person` has exactly one `Address`.  You *can* have a separate `Address` table, but since any given `Person` can have only one `Address` then it would essentially be a 1:1 relationship, so it doesn't *need* to be its own table per se.  It kind of sounds like you're over-thinking the question a bit.  This is practically a textbook example of a relational table structure.  One model (`Person`) has many children (`Phone`), so you'd make a table for `Phone` with a FK back to `Person`.

Comment: It is true that the domain has 1:1 relationship with Address. So given the model example your suggestion is to have 2 tables, Person and Phone, and from Phone i will have FK to Person as i originally thought, but the Address information will be saved in Person table. Thanks for the suggestion